# How is it possible to write $\text {Pr} [M = m]$ where $M$ is random variable defined over a message space $\mathcal M$ and $m \in \mathcal M$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, cryptography

In cryptography we consider random variables $K, M$ and $C$ over the key space $\mathcal K$ , message space $\mathcal M$ and cipher space $\mathcal C$, respectively.

I've studied discrete mathematics and, as far as I know, a random variable $X$ is a function from a sample space $\Omega$ to the real numbers $\mathbb R $.

How is it then possible to write $\text {Pr} [M = m]$ (as is done in many cryptography books), $m \in \mathcal M$ ?

I mean a random variable can never equal to object $m \in \mathcal M$ when its values are real numbers ?

Also, why are we allowed to call $K,M$ and $C$ random variables, when they doesn't satisfy the definition of a random variable ?

Hope someone can help a confused student.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we consider real-valued random variables, but there's no problem at all in allowing $\mathcal M$-valued ones, especially if if $\mathcal M$ is a discrete space.  We could, if we wanted to be pedantic, encode messages by real numbers.

EDIT: For a more general definition of random variables, see e.g.
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition).

Comment: Is there any reason why books don't mention this ? Especially those violating the definition of a random variable ? - Why isn't a random variable defined more general taking values in a set $\Omega$ ? 

What if $\mathcal M$ is not a discrete space ? I mean, is the set of all english sentences a discrete set, I guess not ?

Comment: Since each English sentence is finite, they do form a discrete space.  Discreteness is not necessary either, I just didn't want to get into technicalities about $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: What exactly is a discrete space ? A space that is countable ?

Comment: No, a topological space in which all subsets are open.

Comment: How can one define openess of a message space ? I know how openess is defined with respect to a metric.

Comment: If you want a metric, use the metric $d(x,y) = 0$ if $x=y$, $1$ otherwise.